# When LAN booting is engaging?

Tags: bios, pxe

I have an industrial PC, with Phoenix AwardBIOS. [image]

My goal is to first boot from LAN, even if there is working OS on hard drive. For that First Boot Device is set to Legacy LAN and Second Boot Device is set to Hard Disk. However, if there is working OS installed on hard drive, then PXE never engaged. Instead OS from hard drive is loading. Is this default behavior on all PXE booting computers? Can I somehow force computer to boot from network even though there is working OS on Hard Drive?

UPD:

LAN ROM acting.

[image]

Comment: It should already behave like you desire. If it doesn’t, you’re probably running into a BIOS bug.

Comment: First, deselect "Boot other device". Secondly check if your PXE ROM prompts for a "Press X to boot from network" option - many do, and you can't really do anything about this.

Comment: Disabling "Boot other device "brings me to "DISK BOOT FAILRE, INSERT SYSTEM DISK ND PRESS ENTER", in case there is no OS installed. PXE boot is not engaged in that case. As far as I can see there is no message to press X to boot from network, neigher there is BOOT menu prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
First Boot Device    Legacy Lan
Second Boot Device   Disabled
Third Boot Device    Disabled
```

You should consider your BIOS does not behave correctly; PXE boot should be able to maintain its precedence even if a lower boot priority HDD contains a boot-able OS.

Comment: Even mentioned BIOS settings doesn't work as expected. If there is bootable OS then it boots immediately from HDD, ignoring LAN.

Comment: That's definitely a buggy BIOS. Try to see if this industrial PC has BIOS upgrade capabilities and if a newer version is available..

Answer (score 0):

Go through all your BIOS screens where you will have an option somewhere labeled "Enable PXE ROM" or similar with "ROM" in it. Enabling this will instruct any LAN ROM (PXE) to kick in.

Comment: There is no such item containing word PXE. However, LAN ROM is working properly, but it works after HDD failed to boot system, for some reason. I have added screenshot, showing LAN ROM.